# Изображение в ширину экрана

Tags: html, изображения, css

У меня есть градиентная картинка, и она у меня квадратная, как мне растянуть ее на ширину всего экрана, по высоте пикселей 50? Можно обойтись одним HTML или придется подключать CSS?

Comment: @Александр Гижевский, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Ничего ведь не понятно.

Comment: Я хочу сверху сделать градиентный переход. Нарисовал его в фотошопе, как его растянуть на весь экран на сайте?

Answer (score 3):

Ну, например, так:

```
<img src="..." width="100%" height="50px" alt="" />
```

Только весь этот ваш градиент станет действительно квадратным и некрасивым.

Попробуйте через CSS:

```
background: #ccc; /* Для старых браузров */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ccc); /* Firefox 3.6+ */    
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
    color-stop(0%,#fff), color-stop(100%,#ccc)); /* Chrome 1-9, Safari 4-5 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ccc); /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ccc); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ccc); /* IE10 */
background: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ccc); /* CSS3 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри [background-size](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size).

> Масштабирует фоновое изображение согласно заданным размерам.